# ParseXml fails on some feed xml

Tags: java, xml, parsing, rss, feed

Making a simple rss feed reader, where the user chooses from a fixed site list. It works fine with 20 feeds, but fails in 15 other feeds (which are all 35 valid xml and non valid xsd). App won't crash and logcat has no errors, only warnings.

Some feed that work fine for me are:

- [Katiousa](http://www.katiousa.gr/feed)
- [OmniaTV](https://www.omniatv.com/feed)
- [Provo](https://www.provo.gr/feed/)

Some feed that don't work fine for me are:

- [Info-War](http://www.info-war.gr/feed/)
- [Prin](http://www.prin.gr/feed)

DOMParser

```js
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

public class DOMParser {

    private RSSFeed _feed = new RSSFeed();

    public RSSFeed parseXml(String xml) {

        try {
            // Create required instances
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf;
            dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            // Parse the xml
            Document doc = db.parse(xml);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            int length = nl.getLength();

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

                RSSItem _item = new RSSItem();

                if (nl.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                        Element eElement = (Element) nl.item(i);

                        //Get Link
                        _item.setLink(eElement.getElementsByTagName("link").item(0).getTextContent());

                        //Get Date
                        //Taking pubDate and make it HH:mm dd/MM/yy
                        String TimeDate = eElement.getElementsByTagName("pubDate").item(0).getTextContent();
                        String ZYear = TimeDate.substring(12, 16), ZMonth = TimeDate.substring(8, 11), ZDay = TimeDate.substring(5, 7);
                        String ZHour = TimeDate.substring(17, 19), ZMinute = TimeDate.substring(20, 22);
                        String ZTimezone = TimeDate.substring(26, 30);

                        if (ZMonth.equals("Jar")) {
                            ZMonth = "01";
                        } else if (ZMonth.equals("Feb")) {
                            ZMonth = "02";
                        } else if (ZMonth.equals("Mar")) {
                            ZMonth = "03";
                        } else if (ZMonth.equals("Apr")) {
                            ZMonth = "04";
                        } else if (ZMonth.equals("May")) {
                            ZMonth = "05";
                        } else if (ZMonth.equals("Jun")) {
                            ZMonth = "06";
                        } else if (ZMonth.equals("Jul")) {
                            ZMonth = "07";
                        } else if (ZMonth.equals("Aug")) {
                            ZMonth = "08";
                        } else if (ZMonth.equals("Sep")) {
                            ZMonth = "09";
                        } else if (ZMonth.equals("Oct")) {
                            ZMonth = "10";
                        } else if (ZMonth.equals("Nov")) {
                            ZMonth = "11";
                        } else if (ZMonth.equals("Dec")) {
                            ZMonth = "12";
                        }

                        TimeDate = ZHour + ":" + ZMinute + " " + ZDay + "/" + ZMonth + "/" + ZYear;

                        //Convert date to milliseconds since 00:00 01/01/1970
                        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy");
                        formatter.setLenient(false);
                        Date date_before = formatter.parse(TimeDate);
                        assert date_before != null;
                        long milliseconds = date_before.getTime();

                        //Add time to reach +0200 Athens/Greece
                        if (ZTimezone.equals("0000")) {
                            milliseconds = milliseconds + 7200000;
                        }

                        _item.setDateComparison((int) milliseconds);

                        // add item to the list
                        _feed.addItem(_item);
                    }
                }
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException | IOException | ParseException | SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Return the final feed once all the Items are added to the RSSFeed
        // Object(_feed).
        return _feed;

    }

}
```

logcat warnings

```html
2020-12-28 23:26:34.305 30015-30071/ozma13.riseapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
2020-12-28 23:26:34.423 30015-30071/ozma13.riseapp W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
2020-12-28 23:26:34.530 30015-30071/ozma13.riseapp W/System.err: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document
2020-12-28 23:26:34.533 30015-30071/ozma13.riseapp W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:125)
2020-12-28 23:26:34.534 30015-30071/ozma13.riseapp W/System.err:     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:155)
2020-12-28 23:26:34.534 30015-30071/ozma13.riseapp W/System.err:     at ozma13.riseapp.DOMParser.parseXml(DOMParser.java:30)
2020-12-28 23:26:34.534 30015-30071/ozma13.riseapp W/System.err:     at ozma13.riseapp.MainActivity$AsyncLoadXMLFeed.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:532)
2020-12-28 23:26:34.534 30015-30071/ozma13.riseapp W/System.err:     at ozma13.riseapp.MainActivity$AsyncLoadXMLFeed.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:441)
2020-12-28 23:26:34.535 30015-30071/ozma13.riseapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
2020-12-28 23:26:34.535 30015-30071/ozma13.riseapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2020-12-28 23:26:34.535 30015-30071/ozma13.riseapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
2020-12-28 23:26:34.535 30015-30071/ozma13.riseapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
2020-12-28 23:26:34.536 30015-30071/ozma13.riseapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
2020-12-28 23:26:34.536 30015-30071/ozma13.riseapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
2020-12-28 23:26:35.120 30015-30043/ozma13.riseapp W/ThreadedRenderer: ThreadedRenderer::detachAnimators pid = 30015 threadid = 30043
2020-12-28 23:26:35.183 30015-30043/ozma13.riseapp W/ThreadedRenderer: ThreadedRenderer::detachAnimators pid = 30015 threadid = 30043
2020-12-28 23:26:37.734 30015-30043/ozma13.riseapp W/ThreadedRenderer: ThreadedRenderer::detachAnimators pid = 30015 threadid = 30043
```

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/username/Documents/file_name.txt` that's not a warning...

Comment: @aran oops, sorry... i posted wrong logcat, now it's edited.

Comment: could you post some of the URIs not working? My guess is that you couldn't retrieve the file

Comment: @aran there are two on the post, here are some more not working properly http://www.toperiodiko.gr/feed/ , http://feeds.feedburner.com/epohigr , https://www.mpalothia2.wordpress.com/feed/ ,http://www.narnet.gr/rss.xml . Probably yes, i can't retrieve the files... but can't see why

Answer (score 0):

The answer is switching between "https" and "http" in the non-retrieving xmls. I don't know why but that's the fix for me!